# Convert a webkitrelativepath absoluteto absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webkit

Is there a possibility to convert a folder name in webkitrelativepath to an absolute path string?

I need to add this to my frontend and dont only want the name of the folder. I want it all!

How to do this?

EDIT: is this possible via the `webkitRequestFileSystem`?

Comment: No, it would be a security issue

Comment: @A.Wolff is there a way to get the full path? Not editing or using. Just "creation" of the path string?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you can't convert a relative address to absolute due to security reasons (as mentioned by Wolff).

Something that I found useful, was this:

```
let urlPath = URL.createObjectURL(relativePath);
```

It allowed me to access multiple files from the client-side as blobs, where previously the relative address was giving a 404 error on loading... I know it's not the answer you're looking for, but I hope it's at least a little helpful.